Regex for finding values between underscores
In the following string:
ABCD_HEWD_21.1_220101_R123456789_231010_085204.xml

I need to extract the value before the first underscore and the value between the first and second underscore.
I tried (?!abc)\_ which indicates the underscores.... but I need the surrounding values.
Probably a combination with 'looking forward' or 'ahead' (?<=_)[^_]+(?=_) shall be applicable, I guess?

Use two capture groups? ^([^_]+)_([^_]+) what about this abc, it's not clear at least not to me :D

Or maybe reconsider, whether you need regexp at all here and whether simple split would not do a better job for you.For example in JS, doing var [first, second] = 'ABCD_HEWD_...'.split('_') would do the trick.

You can use the following regex which matches the start of your string and extract the values from the first and second capturing groups :
^([^_]+)_([^_]+)

In this regex

^ matches the start of the string
[^_]+ matches a non-zero sequence of non-underscore characters (negated [character class]). They are in (capturing groups) which will let you retrieve their content.

You can try it here.

This will not work for input: _ABCD_HEWD_21.1_220101_R123456789_231010_085204.xml

@ArtBindu change the + into * if you need to retrieve empty strings, or leave as-is if you don't want to match what could be a malformed string

Yes, right @Aaron

This pattern will match any characters that are between two underscores. The + ensures that at least one character is matched, and the ? makes the match non-greedy, meaning it will stop at the first underscore it encounters after the initial one. The parentheses () create a capture group for the value between the underscores.
If you want to match values that do not contain underscores themselves, you can use:
_([^_]+)_


According to question, you need to extract the value before the first underscore and the value between the first and second underscore.
If input data is:
ABCD_HEWD_21.1_220101_R123456789_231010_085204.xml

Then regex pattern will be: /^([^_]+)_([^_]+)/
But if your input data start with _ then it will not work. For Example:
_ABCD_HEWD_21.1_220101_R123456789_231010_085204.xml

Then regex pattern should be:

/^(([^_]+(\_)[^_]+)|((\_)[^_]+))/gi

Test your regex here: regex101

